# When i type in the textBox a word it's coloring all the items in listView with the text in textBox how to color only the word i type?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the method i'm using to color the items in listView

```
private void ColorListViewItems(Color color, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (textBox4.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        textBox4.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                        {
                            if (ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[i].Text.ToLower().Contains(textBox4.Text.ToLower()))
                            {
                                ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[i].ForeColor = color;
                            }
                            backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(i * 100 / ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Count);
                        }));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And the textBox textchanged event

```
private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox4.Text != "")
            {
                if (backgroundWorker2.IsBusy)
                {
                    backgroundWorker2.CancelAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (backgroundWorker2.IsBusy)
                {
                    backgroundWorker2.CancelAsync();
                    ColorListViewItems(Color.Black);
                }
                else
                {
                    ColorListViewItems(Color.Black);
                }
            } 
        }
```

In the dowork event i just call the method that color

```
BackgroundWorker worker;
        private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            ColorListViewItems(Color.Red, e);
        }
```

And the method to color back to Black

```
private void ColorListViewItems(Color color)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[i].ForeColor = color;
            }
        }
```

The problem is when i type for example in the textBox4 the letter F then it's coloring all the items in the listView(lvnf) that this items text contains the letter F.

Now i keep typing and now in textBox4 there is the letters Form1 so now it's coloring in Red all the items in the listView that it's text contains Form1.
But that's what i thought it's doing but i found out it's just not coloring back to default(Black) the other items that were colored in Red before.

If i typed F many items will be color in red.
But if i type after the F1234567 now what i want it to do is to color all the items back to default color black.

I want that it will consider F1234567 as a word. If i type only F consider it a letter but if it's F1234567 consider it a word so when i type in the textBox F1234567 i want to search for items that the text of them contains F1234567 and not contains F as part of the text.

So if i typed now in the textBox Form1 now if i delete the Form1 and type OCR it should search for the word OCR and not to color items with O in it but only items with OCR

If i type only O then search for O but if i continue to type in the textBox after O i add CR (OCR) now search for OCR. If i delete now the R so search now for OC.
Deleted the C now search for O now i added again CR so search again for OCR.

But now it's searching for any part of the text i type in the textBox as string.
If i type O and then keep typing CR it will remember the O before.
It should now search for OCR and items without OCR should be turn back to Black color if they are colored in RED.

Comment: I messed it up but the idea is if i typed O and now all items with O in Red color now if i keep typing CR so now search for OCR and items that are in Red already and dosent have OCR color them back to Black and only leave or color in Red items with OCR. Leave since when i typed O it's already colored also the OCR items.

Comment: Look at your code.  Do you do anything to change the color back?

Comment: @Paparazzi yes i forgot to add this method i added it now to my question i'm calling this method in the textchanged event if the textBox is empty. Same method name ColorListViewItems but this time getting only one parameter and color all items to black. That's what it does. But this method won't help in my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[i].Text.ToLower().Contains(textBox4.Text.ToLower()))
{
    ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[i].ForeColor = color;
}
else 
{
    ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[i].ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```